# Array of Objects Memory Allocation(Stack And Heap)

Tags: java, arrays, object, memory, memory-management

I have initialised an array of class objects, I'm curious about *how they're allocated in memory(stack and heap*), I found a piece of code from a textbook, it draws the memory allocation on the **left** below.

My **Question** is: **why the memory allocation is not the one I draw on the right**, in the code below, `new Person[]{new Person("Simon", 20)...}`, the `new Person` object would assign its memory address to the `per[0]`,however, the `per[0]` is created in the heap when `Person[] per = new Person[3]` is executed.

**Initialization of an array of class objects**

```
 class Person {
        private String name;
        private int age;
        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
    }

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Person[] per = new Person[]{new Person("Simon", 20), new Person("John", 21), new Person("Willy", 22)};
        }
    }
```

1. [Left(TextBook)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Laf.png)
2. [My Thought](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdooV.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the memory allocation is not the one I draw on the right,

It is on the right, but if you were to use the value

```
per
```

or

```
per[0]
```

that reference would be brought onto the stack.

Comment: Hi Peter,thank you of your reply,  this is the entire code I got on the textbook, which means I didn't use the value of  `per[0]` to do other things, but the author drew that left image made me really confusing...as you see, what I understand is the image I drew on the right, i really don't quite know which one should I go for...

Comment: @Ruizhi an array isn't very useful unless you access it's elements.